# Get network MAC address on WebOS

Tags: webos

can someone explain how to get network MAC address on webOS ?

I looked through the API documentation, neigther of Web API or Luna service API doesnt seem to provide it, but i have seen apps display network MAC before, so they clearly get it from somewhere.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Did you found any solution yet? If yes please help me.